# obd2 battery level on electric vehicle

Tags: python, obd-ii

I'm looking for a way to get the battery level in EV using OBD2 dongle,
I manage to get the fuel level in Toyota and Ford but I need to get data from the battery management systems (BMS) on EV.

I'm using python obd libraries and I have both comma.ai panda and OBDLink-LX dongles.

thanks,
Avi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some cars will report battery level on PID 0x5B of mode 1.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED

You can only get the emission related data from the OBD II.
List of all supported PIDs are available in [ISO 15031-5](https://www.iso.org/standard/66368.html) which is Communication between vehicle and external equipment for emissions-related diagnostics.

This Iso protocol includes all the possible PIDs but does not mean that all the cars are going to support them.

To see which PIDs are supported for a car, you have to firstly check all the available PIDs within each car by querying the `pid 0x00, 0x20, 0x40 ...`. you can find more detail on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs).

Please remember the wiki is the not reliable for the complex PIDs (You have to read the ISO)!!!

> I need to get data from the battery management systems (BMS) on EV.

Here is the [answer from Bolav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47616373/6072457): Some cars will report battery level on PID 0x5B of mode 1.

Comment: Thank you, I understand from experience I made that the EV battery is actually the hybrid battery and on EV cars you can see the status of the battery under hybrid battery status.